# Hide li bullets in bxslider on startup

Tags: css, list, bxslider

I'm using bxslider to show a photogallery. Here's my current setup.

```
<div class="slidercontainer">
    <ul class="slider">
        <li><img src="image1.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="image2.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.slider').bxSlider(
{
    auto: true,
    mode: 'fade',
    pause: 5000
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine, but before image load I can see the list (li) bullets on top left of the slider. I've tried to edit bxslider CSS like this

```
.bx-wrapper ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style:none;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas to hide list bullets on startup?

Comment: Plunker or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the bx-wrapper selector is only added after you use the bxSlider function.

```
.slider ul {
  list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, I've tried to add list-style-type:none; too, but it still doesn't do the trick.

Comment: It means that there is done other css code overriding you. Try adding important!

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing to do. I've also tried to add text-indent rule to list elements to push dots away, but no way.

Comment: Open the developers tools in chrome or Firefox and start messing with the css until it works